# unable to access index for repository

Tags: repository

About the title issue (impossibility to access the package repository from R 3.3.3), now I tried to install version 3.1.1 again: it works and all the repositories can be reached.

Are there any environment variables or registers whose differences between the two versions I can check?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Also - the stuff about other questions, and how to post answers, was superfluous - I edited it out, as it didn't help with this question (which is very unclear).

Comment: This is tagged "accessibility" but is it about supporting users with disabilities? Or is this about being able to gain access to a repository?

Answer (score 0):

An update. I tried other R installations on different PCs.
I remind that the question concerns impossibility to connect to any package repository (even if packages can be downloaded by a browser and then installed locally).
So I resume the results so far obtained:

3.1.1 "Sock it to me" - windows 8 not proxied - ok
3.3.1 "Bug in your hair" - windows 7 proxied - ok
3.3.1 "Bug in your hair" - windows 8 not proxied - notok
3.3.3 "Another canoe" - windows 8 not proxied - notok
3.3.3 "Another canoe" - windows 7 proxied - ok

So, it seems something come with version 3.3.x which likely does not like windows 8, even if I do not know any reported incompatibility.

Unfortunately, my current working machine is precisely the windows 8 machine ...